# Adding a UISwitch to the top of a UITableView to expand/collapse the lower UITableViewCell(s)

Tags: ios, ios5

I am a newbie to iOS development and I am having trouble figuring out how to get a `UISwitch` to expand/collapse a `UITableView` existing `UITableViewCell`s (for example having one `UITableViewCell` with the `UISwitch` on the top cell expanded to 5 `UITableViewCell` rows when the state of the `UISlider` is toggled to `ON` and `OFF` will toggle back to 1 row).  I currently have `UITableViewController` class implemented has static cells with a grouped style (so no `UITableViewDelegate` or `UITableViewDataSource` methods have been implemented). I am working with the latest build of **iOS (iOS 5.1)**.

Any explanation on how to do this or example code would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I don't think you can do this with static cells.

Here's how I'd do it:

- Have a `BOOL` in the table view controller (i.e., the object that is the delegate and data source) that determines whether or not cells 2-5 should be visible
- When the UISwitch is toggled, toggle the `BOOL`, and use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` or `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to make the cells at rows 2-5 appear or disappear (respectively) as appropriate.
- Have `numberOfRowsInSection` determine the right value (1 or 5) depending on whether cells 2-5 should be visible